# Sending data by using python to sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

I am sending data to sql server and the data absolutly perfect , but all of sudden i was encountered with following error , can any one please suggestes me whats the problem is:

**ERROR**

> "Column must be constructed with a non-blank name or "
>
> ArgumentError: Column must be constructed with a non-blank name or assign a non-blank .name before adding to a Table.

I am currently using:
Server: SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

The column that you are trying to send data to cannot contain **NULL** values is what I am assuming. However if you check the column in your dataframe that you are sending to your MySQL server I bet that there are **NULL** or empty values within that column.

You need to make sure that if your column in your MySQL server cannot contain null values, the dataframe column that you are sending to the server cannot have null values also. You will need to insert a value into the dataframe for every null value in that column for the MySQL server to accept the data, or change your database design to allow null values in that column.

That would explain why it was working and why it stopped working. It worked because the server was not receiving **NULL** values but broke the second you tried to send it a **NULL** value into the database.

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback and i will go through with these details.